# how to set name into append input and save it to database with 1 ID. I'm using laravel 5.7 Version

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to get the data from the input added after clicking the button **"add Itinerary"**.

Here is my **code**:

**Views:**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-sm-9" id="dynamic_field">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" name="[]" class="form-control"/>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-sm-9">
            <button type="button" name="add" id="add"  class="btn btn-gradient-primary">Add Itinerary</button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var i = 1;
        $('#add').click(function() {
           i++;
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<div id="row'+i+'" class="input-group"><input type="text" name="[]" class="form-control"/><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></span></div>');
        });

        $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
             var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
             $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
        });
   });
</script>
```

What I want to save the data in a single column in my database using 1 `id`?

Comment: @Inzamam Idress Thank you !

Comment: could u be a bit more clear, you want to store an array of data on a singe row in database, `using 1 id ` what does this means?

Comment: @Leorent Yes . like saving mutiple data from 1 ID